# Two numbers in one node - binomial tree - matrix - tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

In the binomial tree below I want two numbers, one on top of the other, at one node position.  So in the 1st row, 5th column position, I would like 12.625 and then 0.183 below the 12.625.  I want them in the same nodal position of (1,5).

Is it possible to have such a multi-line node?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (tree) [matrix of nodes,column sep=1.5cm]
          {
            &      &        &         & 12.625\\
            &      &        & 11.91   & \\
            &      & 11.236 &         & 11.316 \\
            & 10.6 &        & 10.67   & \\
         10 &      & 10.07  &         & 10.140 \\
            & 9.5  &        & 9.567   & \\
            &      & 9.025  &         & 9.088 \\
            &      &        & 8.574   & \\
            &      &        &         & 8.145 \\
          };
          \draw[->] (tree-5-1)--(tree-4-2);
          \draw[->] (tree-4-2)--(tree-3-3);
          \draw[->] (tree-3-3)--(tree-2-4);
          \draw[->] (tree-2-4)--(tree-1-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-2-4)--(tree-3-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-3-3)--(tree-4-4);
          \draw[->] (tree-4-4)--(tree-3-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-4-2)--(tree-5-3);
          \draw[->] (tree-5-3)--(tree-4-4);
          \draw[->] (tree-4-4)--(tree-5-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-5-1)--(tree-6-2);
          \draw[->] (tree-6-2)--(tree-5-3);
          \draw[->] (tree-5-3)--(tree-6-4);
          \draw[->] (tree-6-4)--(tree-5-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-6-2)--(tree-7-3);
          \draw[->] (tree-7-3)--(tree-6-4);
          \draw[->] (tree-6-4)--(tree-7-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-7-3)--(tree-8-4);
          \draw[->] (tree-8-4)--(tree-7-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-8-4)--(tree-9-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibility is left the node in blank and use it later to put the desired numbers with a vertical shift.

I automatized your code for the arrows too, with the help of a `\foreach` command.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}   
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (tree) [matrix of nodes,column sep=1.5cm,minimum width=1.3cm,minimum height=0.6cm]
          {
            &      &        &         & {}\\
            &      &        & 11.91   & \\
            &      & 11.236 &         & 11.316 \\
            & 10.6 &        & 10.67   & \\
         10 &      & 10.07  &         & 10.140 \\
            &  9.5 &        &  9.567  & \\
            &      &  9.025 &         & 9.088 \\
            &      &        &  8.574  & \\
            &      &        &         & 8.145 \\
          };
    \foreach\i/\j in {5/1,4/2,6/2,3/3,5/3,7/3,2/4,4/4,6/4,8/4}
    {%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\l{\i-1}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\m{\i+1}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\n{\j+1}
      \draw[->] (tree-\i-\j) -- (tree-\l-\n);
      \draw[->] (tree-\i-\j) -- (tree-\m-\n);
    }
    \node at (tree-1-5) [yshift=0.2cm] {12.625};
    \node at (tree-1-5) [yshift=-0.2cm] {0.183};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to force your nodes to have a text width, then you can divide your text in two lines.

[image: two lines node in matrix]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix (tree) [matrix of nodes,column sep=1.5cm,text width=1cm,align=center]
          {
            &      &        &         & {12.625\\0.183}\\
            &      &        & 11.91   & \\
            &      & 11.236 &         & 11.316 \\
            & 10.6 &        & 10.67   & \\
         10 &      & 10.07  &         & 10.140 \\
            & 9.5  &        & 9.567   & \\
            &      & 9.025  &         & 9.088 \\
            &      &        & 8.574   & \\
            &      &        &         & 8.145 \\
          };
          \draw[->] (tree-5-1)--(tree-4-2);
          \draw[->] (tree-4-2)--(tree-3-3);
          \draw[->] (tree-3-3)--(tree-2-4);
          \draw[->] (tree-2-4)--(tree-1-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-2-4)--(tree-3-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-3-3)--(tree-4-4);
          \draw[->] (tree-4-4)--(tree-3-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-4-2)--(tree-5-3);
          \draw[->] (tree-5-3)--(tree-4-4);
          \draw[->] (tree-4-4)--(tree-5-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-5-1)--(tree-6-2);
          \draw[->] (tree-6-2)--(tree-5-3);
          \draw[->] (tree-5-3)--(tree-6-4);
          \draw[->] (tree-6-4)--(tree-5-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-6-2)--(tree-7-3);
          \draw[->] (tree-7-3)--(tree-6-4);
          \draw[->] (tree-6-4)--(tree-7-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-7-3)--(tree-8-4);
          \draw[->] (tree-8-4)--(tree-7-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-8-4)--(tree-9-5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that you can set the text width individually for every column, if you feel that cols 1 and 2 have too much blank space:

```
        \matrix (tree) [matrix of nodes,column sep=1.5cm,text width=1cm,align=center,
            column 1/.style={text width=5mm},
            column 2/.style={text width=8mm},
            ]
```

[image: less blank on cols 1 and 2]

Now, for correct placement of arrows, I suggest you raise a bit your nodes height by a `minimum height=7mm`:

[image: Final draft]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix (tree) [matrix of nodes,column sep=1.5cm,text width=1cm,minimum height=7mm,align=center,
            column 1/.style={text width=5mm},
            column 2/.style={text width=8mm},
            ]
          {
            &      &        &         & {12.625\\0.183}\\
            &      &        & 11.91   & \\
            &      & 11.236 &         & 11.316 \\
            & 10.6 &        & 10.67   & \\
         10 &      & 10.07  &         & 10.140 \\
            & 9.5  &        & 9.567   & \\
            &      & 9.025  &         & 9.088 \\
            &      &        & 8.574   & \\
            &      &        &         & 8.145 \\
          };
          \draw[->] (tree-5-1)--(tree-4-2);
          \draw[->] (tree-4-2)--(tree-3-3);
          \draw[->] (tree-3-3)--(tree-2-4);
          \draw[->] (tree-2-4)--(tree-1-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-2-4)--(tree-3-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-3-3)--(tree-4-4);
          \draw[->] (tree-4-4)--(tree-3-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-4-2)--(tree-5-3);
          \draw[->] (tree-5-3)--(tree-4-4);
          \draw[->] (tree-4-4)--(tree-5-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-5-1)--(tree-6-2);
          \draw[->] (tree-6-2)--(tree-5-3);
          \draw[->] (tree-5-3)--(tree-6-4);
          \draw[->] (tree-6-4)--(tree-5-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-6-2)--(tree-7-3);
          \draw[->] (tree-7-3)--(tree-6-4);
          \draw[->] (tree-6-4)--(tree-7-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-7-3)--(tree-8-4);
          \draw[->] (tree-8-4)--(tree-7-5);
          \draw[->] (tree-8-4)--(tree-9-5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```